# Want to check Internet connectivity in android?

Tags: android

I want to check internet connectivity in my app. but i dont know why my code is not working?

```
public boolean isInternetConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    boolean ret = true;
    if (conMgr != null) {
        NetworkInfo i = conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (i != null) {
            if (!i.isConnected()) {
                ret = false;
            }

            if (!i.isAvailable()) {
                ret = false;
            }
        }

        if (i == null)
            ret = false;
    } else
        ret = false;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: Check whether the permissions added or not

Comment: I use getActiveNetworkInfo() if not null isConnected(), just avoid to null check everything, make sure you have permission as Simple Pan replied

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you added Internet permission like below in your `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: @SP i forget to add this permission in manifest. i'll add and try wait.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method after setting permissions in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Method

```
/**
     * @param activity
     * @return Returns true if there is network connectivity
     */
    public static Boolean checkWIFI(Context activity) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        } else if (netInfo != null
                && (netInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED
                        || netInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTING
                        || netInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.SUSPENDED || netInfo
                        .getState() == NetworkInfo.State.UNKNOWN)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

use this as a general method and pass context of your Activity.

Check the return type of method

if True-- Internet is available

if False-- Internet is not available

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try the code below to explicitly check for **WIFI / Mobile Data** internet connectivity:

```
public static boolean isDataEnabled(Context context)
{
    return (isMobileDataEnabled(context) || isWifiEnabled(context));
}


public static boolean isMobileDataEnabled(Context context)
{
    if(context == null)
        return false;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = null;
    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        networkInfo =
            connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    }
    return networkInfo == null ? false : networkInfo.isConnected();
}

public static boolean isWifiEnabled(Context context)
{
    if(context == null)
        return false;
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
        context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = null;
    if (connectivityManager != null) {
        networkInfo =
            connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    }
    return networkInfo == null ? false : networkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
public static final boolean checkDataConnection(Context cn)
    {
        ConnectivityManager connManager = (ConnectivityManager) cn.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo mData = connManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

        if (mData.isConnected())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

and in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```